# Rattle in my left tire area everytime I brake slowly from more then 80kmh (50mph)?

Tags: brakes, suspension, chevrolet, brake-rotor, delta

I have a Chevy Cobalt 2007, and it has been doing this for a while. If I press the brake a little harder, the rattling stops. It doesnt rattle until I press the brake. Leading me to believe there is a problem with my rotors or my caliper. But it seems more like its my suspension. Please let me know what you think.

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: @MarkJohnson Not really, it still does it all the time. Its getting worse. You?

Comment: Mark johnson, did you figure out what it was? I have a 2012 chevy malibu and its doing the same thing. It is pretty severe on mine and i drive uber so i really need this fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rattle is like a shimmying in the steering column, it's probably a warped rotor.

But if it really is a rattle, take a flashlight and poke around under that wheel to see if your cv boot is ripped or if you can see any damage to the joints leading to the wheel.

It may also be helpful to have someone else hit the brakes while you look to see how they engage on the rotors.  If the shoes are out of wack that could explain things.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I check if the CV boot is ripped? Sorry im a car repair noob!

Comment: @Karl: Take a look at the picture: http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/details/QQEMPIQQAxle_AssemblyQQW0133-1838502.html . A typical front-wheel-drive car has two of those - one end attaches to the transmission, the other to a front wheel. If you take a front wheel off, you should see it clearly. The "boots" are the flexible rubber sheaths that join the thin part in the middle to the thick parts at the ends. If a boot gets ripped, it can cause damage to the CV joint which is inside. (Note: if a boot is intact, it does *not* guarantee that the CV joint is OK.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a look tonight to make sure. My CV joints might be damaged. well see!